# C# application/game, best approach

Tags: c#

I want to create a game something like "Who wants to be millionaire?", where you answer questions by clicking one of the three buttons. I'm kind of noob in c# so I don't know what would be the best approach to do this. I was thinking of making the loop and then creating objects (question - object).
But how would I connect form buttons with these new objects? Or maybe there is a better way to accomplish this?
Thank you all for suggestions!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all: Unless you need your application to run on other platforms than Windows you should look into Windows Presentation Foundation, it's the successor of Winforms.

Regarding how to implement this a simple solution would be to have a CurrentQuestion property containing an instance of a Question class with Answers inside.

```
class Question
{
     public string QuestionText {get;}
     public Answer AnswerA { get; }
     public Answer AnswerB { get; }
     public Answer AnswerC { get; }
     public Answer AnswerD { get; }
     public Answer ChosenAnswer { get;set;}
}

class Answer
{
    public string AnswerText { get; }
}
```

Each buttons Text-property binds to an answer in the CurrentQuestion and when you click the button the answer is chosen and the next question can be processed.

Comment: Thanks, and yes, I'm using WPF.

Answer (score 0):

I will presume that you will do this in windows Forms or WPF (Windows Presentation Foundation) - an application running on a Windows PC and not a web application.

What I would do is to prepare a complete *model* (or object) that would *have* the question and the correct answer which I would use to load a view - a bunch of controls (TextBoxes, Labels, Buttons etc) that would present the information.

Since both Windows Forms and WPF support the notion of *events*, I would hook up handlers the click events of the three button and take action on a click of any of those buttons. And since I loaded the view with the correct answer, I wouldn't have to load anything on the click event which means I could determine if the answer would be correct immediately.

Comment: Well, I probably have to learn a lot because I couldn't really understand what you meant.. I think I'm gonna try and do this my way just to get it to work and then try something different :)

Comment: Try to find some tutorials (videos perhaps) on WPF and take the time to watch them. I think it will save you a lot of time.